# View html file in github repo?

Tags: html, github, repository, topic-modeling

I have a topic modeling visualization created using a python package saved to an html file in my github repository. I tried to open this using - 
 
1. **http://htmlpreview.github.io/** website 
 
 http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/parvathysarat/wordpress-blog-text-mining/blob/master/topicmodeling_vis.html doesn't work, no display 
 
2. **https://rawgit.com** - 403 Forbidden. Not opening new repositories.

Is there an alternative way? It's a public repo.

URL - https://github.com/parvathysarat/wordpress-blog-text-mining/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because the file you're trying to preview isn't a complete HTML document.

Make sure you add `<!DOCTYPE html>`, `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags to make it into a complete HTML document, then try again.

Comment: This is THE solution, the link works now after adding the html tags, Thankyou so much!!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Is this still working? My html page has all the required tags, but it does not render: https://github.com/valeria-io/bokeh-vis-functions/blob/master/dual_axis_bar_line_plot/dual_axis_dual_bar_line.html